# Is it necessary to re-put a collection in another collection after editing it?

Tags: java

In JAVA, I have a HashMap with "Player" objects as Keys, and "ArrayList" as values. It is used to store the opponents for each player. the variable pointing to the hashmap is called playerOpponents.

Now I want to add an opponent to some player. Is it necessary to put the list in the map after editing like in method 1, or not, like in method2?

Method1:

```
private void addOpponent(Player p, Player opponent)
{
    ArrayList<Player> allOpponents = playerOpponents.get(p);
    allOpponents.add(opponent);
    playerOpponents.put(p,allOpponents);
}
```

Method2:

```
private void addOpponent(Player p, Player opponent)
{
    ArrayList<Player> allOpponents = playerOpponents.get(p);
    allOpponents.add(opponent);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to re add it to the hashmap. When you do `.get()`, you'll be getting back a reference to the object.

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to put the list reference every time. Just put `null` check.

```
private void addOpponent(Player p, Player opponent){
    List<Player> allOpponents = playerOpponents.get(p); 
    if(playerOpponents.get(p)==null){
         allOpponents = new ArrayList<>();
         allOpponents.add(opponent);
         playerOpponents.put(p,allOpponents);
    }else
       allOpponents.add(opponent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no. Since `HashMap` already has the list, you just `get` the reference not `remove` it, so its not required to add it again. just add the element to existing list. thats it.

Answer (score 1):

No. `HashMaps` like all other collections store `Object` references. Any change that you make to an object in the `Map` is immediately reflected in the `Object` returned by `HashMap#get` as they are the *same Object*.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to re-put the object.  What your `get` statement is doing is retrieving a reference to the `ArrayList`, NOT a copy of the `ArrayList`.

As another example, say you did this:

```
ArrayList a = playerOpponents.get(p);
ArrayList b = playerOpponents.get(p);
```

Any changes made to `a` are reflected in `b` and vice-versa.  In your case, `a` is the `ArrayList` reference retrieved from the `HashMap` with a `get` method, and `b` is the `ArrayList` reference in the `HashMap`.  Changes to one reference are reflected in the other.

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct way of doing this would be:

```
playerOpponents.get(p).add(opponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The ArrayList referenced by playerOpponent's mapping from Player p will contain 'opponent' without any other function calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, no need to re-put it because you're only changing the VALUE of the key-value map.

However, a subtle gotcha to watch out for: if you ever change the KEY, in other words the Player instance, in a way that affects its equals() or hashCode() methods, then your map can get royally messed up.  If you are using the default equals() and hashCode() implementations, then changing any field in the Player will screw up the map.

In this latter scenario, then you DO need to remove it before the change and re-put it after the change so that it can hash properly to its new hash location.  Or probably simpler, just override the Player class's hashCode() and equals() methods to only consider some immutable field of Player, such as the playerId; then you can use it freely without removing or re-putting (as long as that immutable field is never null).